# find modulo among bat script arguments

Tags: batch-file

```bat
@ECHO OFF 
:Loop 
IF "%1"=="" GOTO completed 
FOR %%F IN (%1) DO IF "%%F"%3==0 echo %%F 
SHIFT 
GOTO Loop 
:completed
```

I write this code for checking data in an array using batch scripting in windows.
run this .bat file on cmd as

[image: screenshot]

but the values which are divisible by 3 are not shown

Comment: Your current `For` loop code does this, `IF "1"3==0 echo 1`. The modulo operation character is a percent, which means that in a batch file it must be doubled. That said the operation is only an arithmetic expression as part of the `Set` command with the `/A` option and you haven't used `Set` to make that arithmetic calculation for you.

Comment: Actually i want to write a program that reads 10 integers and then prints all the numbers that are divisible by 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a couple of problems.  Firstly, you don't need both a `for` loop and a `goto` loop to loop through your script arguments.  Pick one.  Next, `if` statements can't perform math.  They can't calculate a modulo.  You must use `set /a` to calculate the modulo (num % 3).

Here's a working example.

```js
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%I in (%*) do (
    set /a mod = %%I %% 3
    if !mod! equ 0 echo %%I
)
```